# How do I quantify a discrepancy which only exists in a subset of data?

Tags: correlation, standard-deviation, kurtosis

I was looking at two different correlations (`BU`-`OEU` and `BC`-`OEC`) and found them **both to be significantly negative** (see **Figures 1 and 2**).

However, eyeballing the data for the low end of `BU` and `BC` (`> 0.1`) it would appear that there is a **much larger spread of scores for `OEU` than for `OEC`** (ignoring the outlier in `OEC`; see **Figures 3 and 4**).

**Is there a way of quantifying this?** 
I was thinking perhaps kurtosis + standard deviation, but am unsure.

**Figure 1**
[image: Figure 1]

**Figure 2**
[image: Figure 2]

**Figure 3**
[image: Figure 3]

**Figure 4**
[image: Figure 4]

Comment: quiet literally the scatter: bind BU-OEU in a n by two matrix and compute the determinant of the co-variance matrix of that data matrix.

Answer (score -1):

I would just say that the variance of OEU is dependent on BU and increases as BU decreases.
If you need to be more definitive you can divide BU into equal intervals for BU below 0.025 such as [0, 0.05], (0.05, 0.015], (0.015, 0.025].  Test for equality of variance in these three groups. I would expect that you could show that the variance in group 1 and group 2 is significantly larger than in group 3.  Of course doing two pairwise tests requires an adjustment for multiplicty.

Comment: Do you think it would be okay to just state that? I've been taught to constantly back up what I say with statistics/tests, though I'm starting to understand more and more that this can't always be the case.

Comment: Some things are so obvious that they don't require statistical tests.  Observing non-normality from seeing departures of a qq plot from a straight line is another example even though formal goodness of fits tests and test for nonzero skewness are possible.  But I will ammend my answer to suggest a possible test.

Comment: What you have is a clear case of heteroskedasticity. I'm not sure what might be used as a standardized effect size for that. If you can just show the raw scatterplots, that is probably fine; you might also look into *spread-level plots*, & show those.

Comment: Where exactly is the heteroscedasticity, @gung? You might be reading too much into a tiny dataset. I don't even see the "outlier" mentioned in the question: figures 3 and 4 seem to remove about half the data! Michael, your proposed test somehow needs its p-value adjusted for the *post hoc* choice of bins. When that's done, I doubt it will find significant differences.

Comment: @whuber, I'm looking at figure 1, you're right that figure 2 doesn't necessarily show any heteroskedasticity.

Comment: @whuber Yes I would say that if you do two pairwise tests you need a multiplicity adjustment.  Now as I look at the figure and see that there are only 14 points in total, it may be difficult to formally reject equality of variances. Generally speaking variance ratios need to be large to reject equality with the F test.

Comment: Our eyes could be deceiving us here. It may be that the apparent difference is only due to having 2 point out beyond BU=0.04 in Figure 4.

Comment: @gung Figure 1 presents the strongest case for heteroscedasticity but even that figure seems to contain only around 25 points and the points with BC>0.2 are spread out.  So whuber may be right that the F tests would not reject equality of variance (maybe even without a multiplicity adjustment).